# How can I select all elements of a class with a visible parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, visible

**EDIT:** This selector is correct. There bug must be elsewhere in the code. So this question is no longer relevant.

**EDIT2:** The real problem was that my parent class had the inline style "display:inline" attached to it, apparently the visible selector doesn't like display:inline. After I took that out it started working.

**EDIT3:** An inline element with an unset height. JQuery says, anything with a height of zero, is considered invisible, I suppose my element with an unknown height was defaulted to zero.

---

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working..

```
   $('.parent-class:visible .my-class[state!="done"]')
```

I want to select all `.my-class` elements that their `.parent-class` element is visible.
Thank you!

Comment: Is it a typo, or did you actually forget to quote your selector?

Comment: nope, I have it quoted. Sorry!

Comment: So is that the only problem? Thank you

Comment: could you add a bit of html where it's going wrong?

Comment: I've added a demo in the question : )

Comment: Your selector should work perfectly fine: http://jsbin.com/ofakid/2/edit

Comment: Thank you guys, it must be something else then. Sorry. The code is pretty long, and I thought it was the selector because that was the only thing i changed.

Comment: I've updated this question with the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $(".parent-class:visible").children(".my-class[state!='done']").html("i am gone");
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XAnqB/7/

Comment: That will return a boolean, though, and not the `my-class` elements.

Comment: I'll try this, there is something in my selector that is wrong, but it isn't the obvious problem in my example.

Comment: @peirix how will it remove the element ??

Comment: @3nigma Look at your jsfiddle, the output is without the `.my-class` element, since you're selecting the `.parent-class` element and changing its HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector should work, and it does work. In your fiddle, you have not included the jQuery library, so it doesn't work there! See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XAnqB/1/).

Comment: Correct!! I just noticed as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you change the framework in jsfiddle to jquery instead of mootools it works

Answer (score 1):

You have it so all descendents of the parent are selected.  The **space** is the "ancestor operator".

If you want only the direct children, use the > operator:

```
.parent-class:visible  > .my-class[state!="done"]'
```